# how does Gzdoom run doom that is a 16bit application

Tags: port

Hey does anybody know how Gzdoom runs An Old game like doom a 16bit application through Gzdoom source port

reason is because I am working on my own source port for doom but I am stuck on this problem because my source port is made on my 64bit windows 10 computer so any suggestions would be awesome. Also, My project is developed on a 64bit application. My main problem I can't load The Game Because The EXE Is Not Supported On My OS version of windows. Links and Comments Please.

Comment: By definition a port is changing the code for a game (or other app)  that was written for one platform so that it can be run on a different platform.  If your port does not run, it is because you have not yet successfully ported it.  You need to review and change the source code as needed.

Comment: Are you talking about taking the doom source Code? And my code and  Code it to support 64bit application yes or ?. I do understand to a minimum but please be more pacific thanks.

Answer (score 2):

GZDoom can run on modern computers because it's compiled as a completely separate modern program (either 32- or 64-bit). It does not run the original Doom program. Instead, the GZDoom project has changed the Doom source code to make use of modern technologies (e.g. OpenGL). A program that allows an old application to run on new computers would be an *emulator*.

You can find the GZDoom source code [on GitHub](https://github.com/coelckers/gzdoom). You can fork it and add your own changes, then compile that into a modern EXE. If you're trying to make your own Doom levels, [Eevee's tutorial](https://eev.ee/blog/2015/12/19/you-should-make-a-doom-level-part-1/) looks good.

Further reading: ["Source port"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_port) on Wikipedia.